# Firebase show posts if value equals true

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and I need to show post for uses ids equals true, here's my firebase database:

```html
{
  "Following" : {
    "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : {
      "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2" : {
        "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2"
      }
    },
    "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1" : {
      "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : {
        "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1",
        "Username" : "Ali"
      },
      "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2" : {
        "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
        "Username" : "Ali"
      }
    },
    "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2" : {
      "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : true,
      "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1" : true
    }
  },
  "Posts" : {
    "-KduqnVVczZf5uibQiZ-" : {
      "Describe" : "gg",
      "Profile" : "https://twitter.com/2Top/profile_image?size=original",
      "Time" : 14881230655,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Mike",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped906285501.jpg?alt=media&token=0c1a3a3d-6e48-4c4e-ba59-f5646bf8965f"
    },
    "-Ke5gJ00CxbjhOuhzLIx" : {
      "Describe" : "hajj",
      "Time" : 1488318465,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "Mike",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1717103943.jpg?alt=media&token=a85b2488-5ac7-49a7-9ad0-dbf4e6f29389"
    },
    "-KeCuiFmUCpN19zwsTsR" : {
      "Describe" : "a",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488439652,
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1",
      "Username" : "2top",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1913886685.jpg?alt=media&token=c8ad26b2-8f09-453b-b48a-aad9e4d8b5c3"
    },
    "-KeD2fBUQ09HVMrvAneb" : {
      "Describe" : "ee",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488441999,
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1",
      "Username" : "2to7p",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1904338270.jpg?alt=media&token=d200b7fc-15e7-4dc4-9913-59c377929e9e"
    },
    "-KeDfnMWiB7k_4J3FBgZ" : {
      "Describe" : "f12g",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488452517,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "2top",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1872832638.jpg?alt=media&token=80239844-a872-47e2-9689-92d368dd9452"
    },
    "-KeDfrw4inUQFtIDXJHp" : {
      "Describe" : "fg",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488452536,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "2top",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1872832638.jpg?alt=media&token=80239844-a872-47e2-9689-92d368dd9452"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "1DUK1pHEEoaImX8iOOspEMEWCPm2" : {
      "Username" : "Tom"
    },
    "BQOwNdGAeRXiBnVj7ijY1EkFiDC3" : {
      "Username" : "7uthaifah"
    },
    "ECWHIksxJ0Q5SUlIrev4BjnjmrJ3" : {
      "Profile" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1mB5WbUN2s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/r3Z4o-VSODQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Username" : "Jice"
    },
    "I5o3JMpYHwZXQD0t2ogWHCQbrZv1" : {
      "Profile" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1mB5WbUN2s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/r3Z4o-VSODQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Username" : "Mike"
    },
    "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : {
      "Cover" : "http://lucascontabil.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/city-wallpaper-7-400x200.jpg",
      "Profile" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--IAMp28UlmE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAomvV2EM8Ut2nW9j0YE2vRZhJyQBHMsrA/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1",
      "Username" : "Dom"
    },
    "ZxqBgLq4ekUJii05AvV86z0i3mH2" : {
      "Profile" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1mB5WbUN2s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/r3Z4o-VSODQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Username" : "Jone"
    },
    "mZ5jjPNLlcc8OguVzWJLAYhavmg1" : {
      "Profile" : "https://twitter.com/2Top/profile_image?size=original",
      "Username" : "Twitter"
    },
    "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1" : {
      "Profile" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1mB5WbUN2s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/r3Z4o-VSODQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Username" : "Mike"
    },
    "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2" : {
      "Cover" : "http://lucascontabil.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/city-wallpaper-7-400x200.jpg",
      "Email" : "@dd",
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "2277top"
    }
  }
}
```

I have used this method but it doesn't work:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mDatabaseFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Following").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());

    Query q = mDatabaseFriends.orderByKey().equalTo(true);
    mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("UID").equalTo(q.toString());

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
                Getting_Posts.class, R.layout.post_card_design, PostViewHolder.class, mQuery) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Getting_Posts model, int position) {}};
```

I need the query that I use it to show posts if ids = true

Here's my method that I used it but it show the only the first following user:

```
mDatabaseFriends.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot following : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Query X = mDatabase.orderByChild("UID").equalTo(following.getKey());

                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
                        Getting_Posts.class, R.layout.post_card_design, PostViewHolder.class, X ) {}});
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I have update the question, check it now.

Comment: Yeah, every time that you do = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter it basically destroys the old one and replaces it with a new one. You should work with a normal RecyclerAdapter instead of a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in this case, I think.

Comment: In mind, I am a new in programming so can you please give me the perfect solution for that.

Comment: Alright, give me a couple minutes.

Comment: Ok brother, and thanks for trying to help others

Comment: I added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using a regular RecyclerAdapter. With your current database design you won't be able to translate what you want into a single firebase query, so the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is out.

```
mDatabaseFriends.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot following : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                mDatabase.orderByChild("UID").equalTo(following.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Getting_Posts model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Getting_Posts.class);
                        // Here you can add your 'post' to a dataset that you can use to initialize a new RecyclerAdapter
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Another option is to simply change your database design to allow for the use of a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter or a FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter (which is more likely). I think you'll need to use Client-side fan-out to achieve this though.

These links should be relevant to what you're trying to achieve.

[The Firebase Blog: Client-side fan-out](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)

[Firefeed](https://firefeed.io/)

### Edit: Added code specific to this situation

It's been a while and I can't test the code right now, but let me know if this is working for you.

First the adapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Getting_Posts> mdataSet;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Getting_Posts> dataSet) {
        mdataSet = dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_card_design, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(inflatedView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Gettings_Posts post = mdataSet.get(position);
        // Set the properties of the holder
        // I don't know what properties you used in the viewholder so I'll just give an example
        // example: holder.Name.setText(post.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mdataSet.size();
    }

    public void add(int position, Getting_Posts post) {
        mdataset.add(position, post);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
}
```

Use it in the following way.
Declare the following properties in your activity/fragment.

```
ArrayList<Getting_Posts> posts;
private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecycler;
```

In the onCreate initialize them like this.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view); // Replace this with the ID of your recyclerView
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(posts);
mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then add my original solution just replace the following line

```
Getting_Posts model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Getting_Posts.class);
```

with this

```
mAdapter.add(mAdapter.mdataSet.size(), dataSnapshot.getValue(Getting_Posts.class));
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Like I said, I didn't get any time to test it so there might be some errors, but I wanted to give you something to work with. You should be able to find plenty of documentation on RecyclerView and RecyclerAdapter online to help you with solving this.

Comment: this method works with me but it shows for 1 uid only so if post uid equals the first following user uid show post, so it works for the first UID only

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It's working fine for me.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your time, all the methods I have understand them and I will add them later to app, but is there a faster way to do that instead of adding new recycler and wasting time ... I thinks there's a query that I can use it, if there's no way, then I will added your methods, and also thanks again for giving me from your time.

Comment: You might be able to do it with an FirebaseIndexRecyclerView but then you would have to redesign your database. You should try reading the links i added. Also, take a look at Firefeed. it's a twitter clone built with Firebase, it also has a following feature.

Comment: then I will use your method I thinks they will help me better.